# Differentiation on End Points of the interval

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

I am reading about differentiability of functions of the form $f$ : $[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ where f is continuous on the interval. In many of the theorems we usually say that there exists a point $c$ $\in$ $(a,b)$ such that some property of $f$ or $f’$ holds at $c$. Why is it that we usually look at the points inside the interval and don’t say anything about the end points ? An example of this is the mean value theorem. Thanks!

Edit: I know this is quite a general question I was hoping for some intuition on such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that two-sided limits don't technically exist at the endpoints. You need limits to talk about derivatives, since they're defined in terms of limits. Now some authors define 'differentiable on a closed interval $[a,b]$' as differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$ as well as differentiable from the right at $a,$ and differentiable from the left at $b$. You can look those definitions up on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability). The same goes for [continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Directional_and_semi-continuity).

Comment: Fantastic that was great!

Comment: And the reason why the limit does not technically exist at the endpoints is because we would need to talk about values to the left of $a$ and to the right of $b$ which is not in our domain.

Comment: Exactly right!!